# Sales cloud and Service cloud maintenance exam

Tags: servicecloud, sales-cloud, certification

I have given Sales cloud and Service cloud certifications last year. Does that need maintenance exam? How will I know that needs maintenance exam?

These Maintenance exams are not showing in "Maintain Certifications" category in my trailhead account. Showing only "Admin", "App builder" and others.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to trailhead here
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/credentials/verification/

Put your email at the right board and click Request, it will send a notification email about your current credential status

Comment: Yes, it shows active. Does sales cloud and service cloud needs maintenance exam?

Comment: @Anusha.G in your notification email, if the required maintenance module says "No action required today!" then you don't need to do anything, otherwise you need to take Salesforce maintenance exams to keep your Salesforce credentials valid